# Una función me da como resultado un par de comillas simples ¿por qué? Help

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, python-requests

```
def read_seq(inputfile):

    #Read DNA file and remove leftover characters
    
    with open(inputfile,"r") as f:
        seq = f.read()
    seq = seq.replace("\n", "")
    seq = seq.replace("\r", "")
    return seq


def translate(seq):
    
    #Translate DNA to protein
    
    table = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',}
    
    protein = ""

    if len(seq)%3 == 0:
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
            codon = seq[i : i+3]
            protein += table[codon]
    return protein
```

Esa es la función, aplico la primera parte para convertir mi FASTA a una secuencia sin espacios en blanco ni saltos de texto, posteriormente cuando quiero aplicar la función de traducir texto me retorna simplemente esto:

> ' '

No me indica errores y, sinceramente, no encuentro el error :( es un código disponible en la web pero no he leído que a alguien más le de el mismo error

Comment: Puede ser que `len(seq)%3 == 0` sea `False`.

Comment: Si pones el ejemplo al que lo estás aplicando y el resultado esperado, te podremos ayudar mejor!

Comment: En lugar de  `seq.replace("\n", "")` y  `seq.replace("\r", "")` puedes simplemente decir `seq=seq.strip()`, que elimina todos los whitespaces (espacios, \r, \n, \t) al principio y al final del string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que esta parte del código `if len(seq)%3 == 0:` nunca se cumple, por tanto nunca se ejecuta el `if` y la función te retorna `protein=''` que es como lo inicilizaste

Answer (score 1):

Una solución pythonesca:

```
def translate(seq):
    table = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',}

    return "".join([table[seq[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3) if i + 3 <= len(seq)])
```

Usando la sequencia `GATTACA` como entrada, la expresión

```
[for seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)]
```

divide la sequencia en codones de tres letras:

```
['GAT', 'TAC', 'A']
```

Como lo que necesitamos es el aminoacido correspondiente, lo extraemos de la tabla:

```
[table[seq[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)]
```

pero el ultimo codon puede tener menos de tres letras, lo que genera un Key Error, asi que hay que descartarlo con un condicional:

```
[table[seq[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3) if i + 3 <= len(seq)]
```

Lo que produce:

```
['D', 'Y']
```

Ahora sólo queda concatenar los aminoacidos:

```
"".join([table[seq[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3) if i + 3 <= len(seq)])
```

lo que nos da:

```
DY
```

Comment: ¡Gracias a todos! en especial a Candid Moe c: ya se solucionó con esa magnífica solución pythonesca